# Data not populating using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery

I am posting this issue after searching through the internet. I didn't find any help or solution and so need your immense support and help on this matter.

I am trying to populate the asp.net textboxes, asp.net dropdownlists and asp.net checkboxes using jquery ajax. The data is getting fetched from WCF services smoothly.

Now, the problem is: when I am debugging the code in Firefox / IE / Chrome, the data is being debugged properly and also getting populated to respective controls. But, if I run the application without debugging in any browser, its not populating the data correctly, specially the dropdownlists and checkboxlists.

The overall code is very long, so I am providing brief code:

**dropdownlist**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReporting" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="--- Select ---" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The rest of data is being populated using jquery ajax and its getting successfully populated.

**The way I am setting the value using jquery to the dropdownlist**

```
$('select[id=ChildContent_ddlReporting]').val(response.REPORTING_MANAGER);
```

**checkboxlist**

```
<div id="divTeamList">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Badri" value="1" onchange="toggleValue('divModuleAccessList','Modules','hidModulesIdList','txtModules');">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Amrita" value="2" onchange="toggleValue('divModuleAccessList','Modules','hidModulesIdList','txtModules');">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The way checkbox list is getting populated using jquery ajax**

```
if (response.TB_ES_USER_TEAMS != null) {
    $.each(response.TB_ES_USER_TEAMS, function (index, itemData) {
        $('#divTeamList input:checkbox[value="' + itemData.TeamId + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });

    toggleValue("divTeamList", "Teams", "hidTeamIDList", "txtUserTeam");
}
```

Now, the issue is that sometimes data is getting set to respective controls correctly and sometimes its not. Its showing no errors also.
If I debug using firebug, its coming and if I don't debug then its not getting populated correctly sometimes.

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry: I copied the id wrong. Actually the id(s) are - Badri and Amrita respectively.

Comment: There are some key parts missing in your presentation. 1: How is the function `toggleValue()` defined? 2: What is the data model of the ajax response `response.REPORTING_MANAGER` and respectively `response.TB_ES_USER_TEAMS`? Can you show a (verified) sample response?

Comment: response: {"DESIGNATION":"SE","EMAIL_ID":"agnib@gmail.com","FIRST_NAME":"Agnib","LAST_NAME":"Pyne",TB_ES_USER_TEAMS":[{"TeamId":"2","TeamName":null},{"TeamId":"4","TeamName":null}].             Can you please tell me how to edit the question and rectifty that mistake?

Comment: And the `toggleValue()` function?

Comment: I observed that when I am debugging the jquery code using chrome or IE, its populating the data but if I run without debugging, then sometimes the data is being shown. How strange it is? I cannot understand what to do

Comment: do I need to load the popup form first and then set the values or after setting the values we need to load the form?

Comment: A common problem when dealing with ajax data is if elements are added dynamically jQuery functions won't run if not an event handler is set. Now I cant see all your code but make sure `on()` handler is used for events to trigger on dynamically added items. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ If you want more help you really need to add all code that might be involved.